# How can I update an object metadata through Google Cloud Storage using Python aiohttp PATCH request?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to update an object metadata through Google Cloud Storage using Python aiohttp PATCH request, code attempt as follow.

```
async def send_init_value_map(sequence_name):
    """Update a blob's metadata."""
    initial_value_map = {"metadata", "value": {'test':0}}
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        await session.patch(url=api_url, headers=headers, data=initial_value_map)
    return initial_value_map
```

The `url` and `headers` in the patch request are good, as they worked in GET request. However, I'm not sure if I'm passing the `data` field right, the change didn't take effect.

Info on PATCH within aiohttp documentation is limited, as the format for `data` field input is not specified.
[image]

I'm not going with the Google API Client option because I need to use aiohttp for async function implementation.

Thank you in advance for you inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert the data dictionary to json first. After that, the data was successfully updated.

```
async def send_init_value_map(sequence_name):
"""Update a blob's metadata."""
initial_value_map = {"metadata", "value": {'test':0}}
async with ClientSession() as session:
    await session.patch(url=api_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(initial_value_map))
return initial_value_map
```